# OpenGL version is not high enough

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I would like to install and run this Met.3D software (https://met3d.wavestoweather.de/met-3d.html), but the documentation mentions that it requires the system to have at least OpenGL 4.3. Here is an image of the system requirement mentioned in the documentation of the software.

[image: system requirement]

When I checked the OpenGL version for my GPU in Ubuntu 22.04, it says that my core profile is only up to OpenGL 4.1, even though I checked with OpenGL Extensions viewer says that it can support up to OpenGL 4.6. My current GPU is the Intel iRIS Xe Graphics.

This is what is shown in my Ubuntu:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 4.1
    Max compat profile version: 4.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL version string: 4.1 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 22.2.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

This is what is shown in OpenGL Extensions viewer.

[image: OpenGL Extensions viewer]

I updated mesa to version 22.2.5 with oibaf already, but my OpenGL version on Ubuntu is still 4.1. Is getting a new GPU/computer the only thing that I can do? Or is this just a driver problem. What can I do if I would like to run the program?

Comment: Indeed, [Intel iRIS Xe Graphics](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/211014/intel-iris-xe-dedicated-graphics-card-80-eu.html) has OpenGL 4.6 support, but, apparently, not on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL version depends on GPU hardware. You can check which OpenGL version is supported by your GPU at a vendor site.

If you get a graphics card, e.g. Nvidia or AMD, you should get 4.3+ OpenGL version.

For example I have an ancient Nvidia GeForce GT550Ti and it supports 4.6.

Also `mesa` is sometimes slow in implementing OpenGL versions. Possibly future versions may add support.